# On the gameStart court open function, it looks neat but It won't adjust on mobile

Tags: javascript, html

I am doing autofit with width and height tags on a js var called myFeatures for my game to open in another window, it works fine on a laptop, however, when I try to do the same steps in mobile, it shows the court.gif multiple times and zoomed out. I want it to be zoomed in just like in my laptop.

I tried doing style and css but it did not work.

This is on the gameStart page, and when you clicl the button, the game.html page pops up.

```
var myFeatures = "height=495,width=300";
var court = window.open("game.html", "bbCourt", myFeatures);
court.focus();
```

Then in the `game.html` I have this as I said I tried to do padding, top, bottom, left and right (auto and 0 for all sides) but it did not work. I was doing this at the same time with and without myFeatures.

There are no specific error messages; I just want to adjust this properly in a mobile instance, and whenever I try to inspect and change devices it won't let me, since it's a pop-up window I assume?

The code is here:

[gameStart.html](https://github.com/Alfonso-Jim/Glued_Shoe_Basketball/blob/master/gameStart.html)

[game.html](https://github.com/Alfonso-Jim/Glued_Shoe_Basketball/blob/master/game.html)

Screenshots:

[dekstop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2iAWs.png)

[mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rS005.png)

Comment: share also your html and css

Comment: updated content, thoughts?

Comment: ok, do you have tried to use a img tag for court.gif ? make body in position relative and use `<img src="court.gif" calss="abs">`   `body{position: relative} .abs{position: absolute; width: 100%; height: auto; top:0; left:0;right:0;bottom:0; z-index: 1}` and put `<img src="court.gif" calss="abs">` immedially after body opening tag